# PageMenu error , UICollectionView received layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewlayout, collectionview

I use PageMenu, swipe transition library.
https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu

When I transition new collectionViewController, it is good.

But when I swipe back to existing collectionViewController, it always crash.

I read other stackoverflow posts and found two solutions. I tried these solutions but it crashed.

**First Solution**

```
override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    return 1
}
```

**Second Solution**

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    collectionView?.reloadData()
}
```

**Error log**

What is the problem?

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UICollectionView received layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist: <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000018016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 3}'
```

Comment: Hi, what was the solution?

Comment: You may want to check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38423783