# UICollectionView received layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist: <NSIndexPath: 0x79fe0f20> {length = 2, path = 0 - 4}

Tags: swift

When I load the first time my UICollectionView does not have any problem, Im using custom layouts and a serachbar, when I search some text it crashes throwing the exception that the cell with an index path that does not exist, Im using the search bar like the next code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class CategoryViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {

    var ListArray : JSON! = []
    var SelectedIds: [Int] = []
    var SearchActive : Bool = false
    var SearchArray = [Int]()

    @IBOutlet weak var SearchCategories: UISearchBar!

    @IBOutlet weak var CategoryCollection: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let layout = self.CategoryCollection.collectionViewLayout as? InterestsLayout {
            layout.delegate = self
        }

        self.CategoryCollection.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        self.CategoryCollection.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 18, left: 3, bottom: 10, right: 3)

        // Search Delegate
        self.SearchCategories.delegate = self
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.LoadData()
    }

    func LoadData() {
        MUBService.categoriesList(self) { (categories_list) -> () in

            self.ListArray = categories_list
            self.CategoryCollection.reloadData()

            self.view.hideLoading()

        }
    }

    func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
        self.SearchCategories.showsCancelButton = false
    }

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.SearchCategories.showsCancelButton = true
        self.SearchActive = true
    }

    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.SearchActive = false
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.SearchActive = false
        self.dismissKeyboard()
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.SearchActive = false
    }

    func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, let textDidChange searchText: String) {
        self.SearchArray = []
        for (index, object) in self.ListArray["categories"] {
            let name = object["name"].string!
            if name.localizedStandardContainsString(searchText) == true {
                self.SearchArray.append(Int(index)!)
            }
        }


        if(self.SearchArray.count == 0){
            self.SearchActive = false;
        } else {
            self.SearchActive = true;
        }


        self.CategoryCollection.reloadData()
    }

}

extension CategoryViewController {


    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

        self.CategoryCollection?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if(self.SearchActive && self.SearchArray.count > 0) {

            return self.SearchArray.count
        }

        return self.ListArray["categories"].count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CategoryCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CategoryCell

        let row = indexPath.row

        if(self.SearchActive && self.SearchArray.count > 0) {

            let category = self.ListArray["categories"][self.SearchArray[row]]
            cell.configureWithPhoto(category, selected: self.ListArray["selected"])
        }else{

            let category = self.ListArray["categories"][row]
            cell.configureWithPhoto(category, selected: self.ListArray["selected"])
        }
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


        let cell = self.CategoryCollection.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CategoryCell

        cell.changeBackGroundColor()
        if (cell.is_active == true){
            self.SelectedIds.append(cell.id)
        }else{
            self.SelectedIds.removeObject(cell.id)
        }

    }

    @IBAction func RegisterDidTouch(sender: AnyObject) {

        MUBService.setMyCategories(self.SelectedIds, view_controller: self) { (categories_selected) -> () in
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("HomeTabBarFromCategoriesSegue", sender: self)

        }
    }
}

extension CategoryViewController : InterestsLayoutDelegate {
    // 1. Returns the photo height
    func collectionView(collectionView:UICollectionView, heightForPhotoAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath , withWidth width:CGFloat) -> CGFloat {

        var row = indexPath.row

        if(self.SearchActive && self.SearchArray.count > 0) {

            row = self.SearchArray[row]
        }

        let category = self.ListArray["categories"][row]
        let url = NSURL(string:category["image"].string!)
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL:url!)
        let image = UIImage(data:data!)!
        let boundingRect =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))
        let rect  = AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect((image.size), boundingRect)

        return rect.size.height
    }

    // 2. Returns the annotation size based on the text
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, heightForAnnotationAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, withWidth width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {

        let annotationPadding = CGFloat(4)
        let annotationHeaderHeight = CGFloat(17)

        var row = indexPath.row
        if(self.SearchActive && self.SearchArray.count > 0) {

            row = self.SearchArray[row]
        }
        let category = self.ListArray["categories"][row]

        let font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 10)!
        let rect = NSString(string: category["name"].string!).boundingRectWithSize(CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)), options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)
        let commentHeight = ceil(rect.height)
        var height = annotationPadding + annotationHeaderHeight + commentHeight + annotationPadding
        if (height != 70){
            height = 70
        }
        return 70
    }
}
```

I don't understand what is happening, thanks a lot for your help

Comment: did you find solution to this problem?

Comment: No, do you? I still have the same issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've faced the same problem. Here an explanation: if you use a custom collectionViewLayout and you have a cache for layout attributes (best practice so you don't have to calculate every time attributes), **you have to override invalidateLayout method** in your custom layout class and purge your cache.

Here's my layout attributes array

```
private var cache = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
```

Here the overrided method

```
    override func invalidateLayout() {
    super.invalidateLayout()
    cache.removeAll()
}
```

I call layout invalidation in my textDidChange delegate

```
    func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchText.characters.count > 0 {
        // search and reload data source
        self.searchBarActive    = true
        self.filterContentForSearchText(searchText)
        self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }else{
        self.searchBarActive = false
        self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to have helped you @MarwanZakariya!